# How to fix the order total error on this html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fix this error when an item is added to the cart that the order total is displayed as "£NaN" (as shown in the  image below) and that doesn't change as each item is added. I have looked through the code but couldn't see anything that was out of place or that shouldn't be there, so I don't really know whats causing the problem.

Any suggestion would be amazing.

[image]

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imageSrc}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('£', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '£' + total
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Generics | Store</title>
        <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
        <script src="store.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <nav class="main-nav nav">
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">MUSIC</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 1</span>&nbsp;
                        <span class="shop-item-price">£12.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 2</span>&nbsp;
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">£14.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button"type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 3</span>&nbsp;
                        <span class="shop-item-price">£9.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Album 4</span>&nbsp;
                        <span class="shop-item-price">£19.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">MERCH</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">T-Shirt</span>&nbsp;
                        <span class="shop-item-price">£19.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Coffee Cup</span>&nbsp;
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">£6.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-items">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-total">
                <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                <span class="cart-total-price">£0</span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
        </section>
        <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="container main-footer-container">
                <ul class="nav footer-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
                            &nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.spotify.com" target="_blank">
                            &nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                            &nbsp;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You did not put image tag. But in javascript you are trying to call.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header class="main-header">
    <nav class="main-nav nav">
    </nav>
</header>
<section class="container content-section">
    <h2 class="section-header">MUSIC</h2>
    <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 1</span>&nbsp;
            <span class="shop-item-price">£12.99</span>
            <img class="shop-item-image" src="">image tag
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Album 2</span>&nbsp;
        <div class="shop-item-details">
            <span class="shop-item-price">£14.99</span>
            <img class="shop-item-image" src="">image tag
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Album 3</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="shop-item-price">£9.99</span>
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="">image tag
        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Album 4</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="shop-item-price">£19.99</span>
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="">image tag
        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="container content-section">
    <h2 class="section-header">MERCH</h2>
    <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">T-Shirt</span>&nbsp;
            <span class="shop-item-price">£19.99</span>
            <img class="shop-item-image" src="">image tag
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Coffee Cup</span>&nbsp;
        <div class="shop-item-details">
            <span class="shop-item-price">£6.99</span>
            <img class="shop-item-image" src="">image tag
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="container content-section">
    <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>
    <div class="cart-row">
        <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
        <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
        <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-items">
    </div>
    <div class="cart-total">
        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
        <span class="cart-total-price">£0</span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
</section>
<footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="container main-footer-container">
        <ul class="nav footer-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
                    &nbsp;</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.spotify.com" target="_blank">
                    &nbsp;</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                    &nbsp;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
<script>
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imageSrc}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('£', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '£' + total
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I don't want an image. So How do I remove it from the javascript?

Comment: Didn't you say that it was trying to call an image tag from the javascript. Do I still need to remove it?

Comment: Yeah because if you do not have that tag it will through error in console.

Comment: Are you able to edit your answer and add the correct javascript code?

Comment: You mean to say the code what posted before you want me to update same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208865/discussion-between-krishna-and-t-e).

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong HTML.

I comment `imageSrc` and added missed tags `<div class="shop-item">`

https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/vLfzpjq9/10/

Comment: Yes, I removed it: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/tomvxges/1/